# Multiple gateways/nameservers for physical and a logical interface (on same physical interface)?

Tags: networking, network-interface

I am trying to understand the relation between gateway, nameserver configuration of the interface; and it's relation with physical/logical interface. e.g. if I have a machine with one physical e.g. eth0 and a logical interface e.g. eth0_1 on eth0; where does the Gateway apply ? Can I have two different gateways for eth0 and eth0_1 in this case? Or two different nameservers?

Answer (score 2):

For Gateway, for every subnet you can have a gateway which is the ip address of the NIC that you want to go through, for example 192.168.1.0/24 you can have a gateway for this subnet which is your ip on that NIC.

For default Gateway, No, in general you can't have two different default gateway on the same machine, because that will be ambiguous for the system to determine on which interface it will send the packet that doesn't match any row in the route table except the one which match every things .

For Nameserver, Yes, you can identify two nameservers for every interface, and you can put more nameservers to the whole system.

Comment: Is gateway always "default", i.e. one per machine? Or there can be multiple Gateways and one of them assigned as "default" e.g. like routes we add where we have one "match all default rule"?

Comment: @spa i edited my answer